# Python: Change Initial Directory for Open File Dialog

Tags: python, user-interface, winapi

How to change initial directory for opening file dialog?
Even after specifying the initial directory in my Python code, the dialog still shows my Desktop.

```
from pydantic import DirectoryPath
import win32gui, win32con, os
import pandas as pd

def open_file_dialog():
    initial_dir = 'C:/Users/i12389e/Documents'             #<-----
    filter= "Excel Files\0*.xlsx;*.xlsm;"
    # customfilter='Other file types\0*.*\0'
    fname, customfilter, flags=win32gui.GetOpenFileNameW(
        InitialDir=initial_dir,                            #<-----
        Flags=win32con.OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT|win32con.OFN_EXPLORER,
        File='somefilename', DefExt='.xlsx',
        Title='Open file',
        Filter=filter,
        FilterIndex=0)
    file_directory = fname
    return file_directory

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = open_file_dialog()
    print(a)
```

Based on [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamew) I should use argument `lpstrInitialDir` instead of `InitialDir`. But then an error message showed up:

```
TypeError: 'lpstrInitialDir' is an invalid keyword argument for OPENFILENAME()
```

Thank you in advance for any pointer. I am struggling with it since almost 2 hours.

Comment: Have you tried Windows paths syntax "c:\blah\blah..."

Comment: `'C:/Users/i12389e/Documents'` is the poor-man's spelling of [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath). It's a bug, too.

Comment: @SimonMourier Also not working with \

Comment: @IInspectable Can you be more specific? A short code example in Python would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

`win32gui` maps `InitialDir` to `lpstrInitialDir`.

`lpstr` is part of Hungarian Notation which has gone out of fashion some time ago, but still has to be used in many places by C programmers.

I think your problem is more related to algorithm used by Windows to select initial directory.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea

> The algorithm for selecting the initial directory varies on different platforms.
> Windows 7 and latter:
>
> 1. If `lpstrInitialDir` has the same value as was passed the first time the application used an Open or Save As dialog box, the path most recently selected by the user is used as the initial directory.
> 2. Otherwise, if `lpstrFile` contains a path, that path is the initial directory.
> 3. Otherwise, if `lpstrInitialDir` is not `NULL`, it specifies the initial directory.
> 4. If `lpstrInitialDir` is `NULL` and the current directory contains any files of the specified filter types, the initial directory is the current directory.
> 5. Otherwise, the initial directory is the personal files directory of the current user.
> 6. Otherwise, the initial directory is the Desktop folder.

Analyze these steps and try to guess how system reacts after you call `GetOpenFileNameW`.

A lot more control in specifying initial parameters offers `IFileOpenDialog`, but it is COM-based and I don't know how hard it would be to use it from Python.

For `GetOpenFileNameW`, I would try to add path to `File` argument (make sure that specified path exists), and if problem still persist, put random path into `InitialDir` to avoid point `1.`.

Comment: I still can't figure out, how I could define the initial directory. That's why  I only thumbs up your solution.

Comment: What "define" means in this case? Are you asking about `SHGetKnownFolderPath` or not sure if you correctly pass argument `InitialDir=initial_dir` to `win32gui.GetOpenFileNameW` or why system sometimes ignores it?

Comment: Hey Daniel Sek, the second one. I want to specify the initialdir and could not understand why "InitialDir" doesn't seem to do anything. What I want is that the open file dialog should always start from e.g. c:/Documents/My Project.... Thank you in advance.